# How to use different columns of a csv file data as different layers for weighted overlay analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, weighted-overlay

I have a CSV file like this:
 [image: csv file]

I would like to do a weight overlay analysis for each column of the CSV and present it as a layer of the map of United States of America.

The final result should look like this map:
[image]

Comment: I'd import the csv through Layer->Add Layer->Add delimited text layer. If you have geometry, use it, otherwise get the corresponding Area shapefile from somewhere and perform a table join on the name (you might need to update the Area name column). Once that done, duplicate the layers (right click on it -> duplicate) until you have enough version to carry out the analysis you want to do. You need to add more details to your question if hope to obtain a more detailed answer (such as an example of the result you want to obtain).

Comment: @Victor get shape file as xml and shp file , how can it can be joined with original csv file ?

Comment: You have to import the data as @Victor described. Than you can perform join tables by uniqe coresponding attribute in data. Joins menu is in vector layer properties, see [QGIS Joins documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=join#joins-menu)

Comment: i imported the file and trying to join but i m getting NULL of all the columns joined frm csv file to the shapefile

Comment: Do you want your final unit of analysis to be counties or states?

Comment: @the_darkside counties

Answer (score 1):

For the county shapefile, you can download from [US Census](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html).
Use the 20m zip.  Unzip and import into QGIS, call it `counties`

When you open the shapefile, you will notice that there is a column called `STATEFP` - that is the FIPS code.  Each state has a unique FIPS code and you can find the key [here](https://www.mcc.co.mercer.pa.us/dps/state_fips_code_listing.htm).

What you'll need to do is copy these 52 codes and their corresponding state abbreviation (if you include Puerto Rico and Guam) into a spreadsheat. You should have two columns.  Save this as a csv and import into QGIS as a delimited text layer - call it `stateKey`.  Then, in your csv file with all of your demographic data - split the `Area_name` column using a comma separator which will create two seaprate columns - `County Name` and `State Abbreviation`.  You can do this with the `Data > Text to Columns` in OpenOffice and there is a similar function in Excel. Then import all of your data into QGIS as a delimited text layer, call it `data`.

Now you will perform a few joins.  First, you will join the `stateKey` to `counties`.  Right click `counties` > properties > joins then join `stateKey` by the FIPS code and keep all columns.

Now you have a `counties` shapefile with state abbreviations.

Next, perform the same step, except this time join `counties` to `data` by state abbreviation.  And voila.

Now you can classify the counties by whichever attribute you choose.  For example.  Right click `counties` > properties > style > graduated.   Then you can choose the `column` which you want to visualize.

For more complex modeling, you could consult the Processing Modeler [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_graphical_modeler.html)

Comment: my map became invisible when i changed style > graduated :(

Comment: under `graduated`, after choosing the column ,then you have to use `classify` and then hit `apply`

Comment: it did that still map is not visible